# Python - Enclosing time data from another table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have these two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'C',
  4: 'C'},
 'IdOrder': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2},
 'TrackDateTime': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-21 23:28:35'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-28 17:12:15'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-07 12:41:48'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-01 22:13:44'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-01 22:49:53')}})
df_1
```

[image]

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'A',
  1: 'B',
  2: 'C',
  3: 'D',
  4: 'E'},
 'InitialDate': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-21 23:28:35'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-07 12:41:48'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-01 22:13:44'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-02 15:45:10'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-01-02 22:21:36')},
 'EndDate': {0: Timestamp('2020-01-28 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2020-01-08 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2020-01-03 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2020-01-06 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2020-04-10 00:00:00')}})
df_2
```

[image]

And I'm looking to enclose each `id` in `df_1` with the `InitialDate` and `EndDate` from `df_2`, which would give this expected output:

[image]

Also please consider that:

- `IdOrder=0` for `InitialDate` and `IdOrder=-1` for `EndDate`
- I would like to keep the time granularity up to seconds (the output image doesn't show it because of the excel format)

I haven't been able to figure out a solution for this. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and a custom sorting:

```
tmp = (
    df_2[df_2['id'].isin(df_1['id'])]
 .rename(columns={'InitialDate':0, 'EndDate': -1})
 .melt('id', var_name='IdOrder', value_name='TrackDateTime')
)

out = (pd.concat([tmp, df_1])
         .sort_values(by='IdOrder', key=lambda s: s.replace(-1, np.inf))
         .sort_values(by='id')
       )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
  id IdOrder       TrackDateTime
0  A       0 2020-01-21 23:28:35
0  A       1 2020-01-21 23:28:35
1  A       2 2020-01-28 17:12:15
3  A      -1 2020-01-28 00:00:00
1  B       0 2020-01-07 12:41:48
2  B       1 2020-01-07 12:41:48
4  B      -1 2020-01-08 00:00:00
2  C       0 2020-01-01 22:13:44
3  C       1 2020-01-01 22:13:44
4  C       2 2020-01-01 22:49:53
5  C      -1 2020-01-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you! If you have suggestions for the title, I'm all ears (I don't feel that the title can help someone with the same problem to find this question/answer, but still it's the best description I can think of)